# Dynamic Filtering based on unique values of ArcGIS vector layer field

Tags: arcgis-pro, filter, vector-layer

I'm trying to achieve in ArcGIS some sort of dynamic filter where the software would propose filtering options based on unique values in a vector layer field. This is similar to how PowerBI or Tableau software propose automatic filtering options (and even excel) (see example in PowerBI hereafter).

[image]

I found a plugin in QGIS doing exactly that (Get Them Filtered - https://www.xl-optim.com/get-them-filtered/ | https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/getthemfiltered/), but cannot find anything similar for ArcGIS.

Am I missing something, or am I out of luck, and will need to create manual queries every time for the values I need?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a [definition query in ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/mapping/layer-properties/definition-query.htm#:%7E:text=Definition%20queries%20allow%20you%20to,the%20dataset%20by%20the%20layer.).  A definition query allows the user to filter data based on attributes in the attribute table.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but unless I'm missing some other functionality, if I had a feature class with a field with let's say 500 rows and 50 different values, I would have to manually define 50 different definition queries, which is not ideal for what I want, and also would need to be updated whenever a new unique value appears.
I was looking for something that would create that automatically based on the unique value of a field

Comment: You don't *ever* have to manually define DQs. I think the issue here is the definition of "automatic". It's not exactly best practice to show a 500-row feature class as 50 different layers, so OOTB functionality to do that isn't going to be a priority.

Comment: @Frank - Based on your reply maybe consider symbolizing by unique values?  Then export as a layer file once symbology has meet your needs, edit as needed when new classes are created.  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/mapping/layer-properties/unique-value.htm

Comment: thanks, symbology might have been a good idea, but apparently it is still not possible to use it to quickly turn on/off by symbol (see https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/toggle-visibility-for-individual-categories-on/idi-p/928481).
For the moment I will rely on Display Filters with "Includes the value(s)" operator, which is the closest to what I'd need.